# Story where society is modelled after bees, males may be sacrificed?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a short story approximately 22 years ago (though I think the book was much older), where a group of humans travel to a new world/time? Where there are giant bees and the humans who live there have modelled their society after the hive structure. The males are considered drones and only good for mating and sacrifice to the giant bees.

Comment: Makes me think of Aldiss' [*Hothouse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hothouse_%28novel%29).

Comment: @DavidW, thanks for the suggestion. I looked at Hothouse, and believe the story I'm looking for to be similar in tone, and some basic details, but not it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm reminded of "[Day of the drones](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?12176)" by A.M. Lightner, published in 1969. Although this is a novel rather than a short story, it has a number of features in common with the question.

It is set in a world 500 years after a devastating nuclear war where civilization has only survived in Africa. Travelling in a solar-powered helicopter, some explorers from  the tribe travel north and eventually reach England. There they find giant mutated insects, and a settlement of white people whose matriachal culture is copied from the social structure of the bee hive. The story is told from the viewpoint of an young African woman called Amhara, who falls in love with a handsome "drone", Evan, who is destined to be sacrificed in the same way that bee hives get ride of excess males.

The US cover summarises the plot as "An incredible adventure in the radioactive ruins of the world, where whites live like insects and the blacks are the elite.", while the German cover more entertainingly just includes an illustration of all the main plot-points.

[image: US and German book covers of "The Day of the Drones"]

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. This is the book. I read it quickly when I was young, so I assumed it must have been a short story. I'm searched for this book for years. Glad I decided to post here!

Comment: Glad to help! It was a very progressive novel for its time, with a young black woman as the protagonist.